# How can I reverse the axes in 3d graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

Just starting with 3D plotting in Matplotlib. In the image below, how can I reverse the x and y axes and have a common origin of 0 for both the axes as written in red ink ? I could not find something specific to this case. All help would be appreciated. I tried the following code but the data changes when I change both x and y axes together.

```
ax.set_xlim3d(0, 500)
ax.set_ylim3d(0, 5000)
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 0.0035)

ax.set_xlabel('Frequency [Hz]', labelpad=10)
ax.set_ylabel('Wheel Speed [RPM]', labelpad=10)
ax.set_zlabel('Amplitude Spectrum [V]', labelpad=10)

ax.invert_xaxis()
ax.invert_yaxis()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4.,35))
plt.rcParams["figure.dpi"] = 350
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The 3D plot is interactive. You can rotate it by 180°. Alternatively, set a different viewing angle with `ax.view_init(elev=123, azim=456)`

Comment: @Mr.T This does not reverse the axes for me.

Comment: You did not actually use these placeholder values 123 456, did you? Default [elev is 30, azim is -60](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html), so to rotate it by 180°, you have don't have to touch elev and set azim to 120. If you move the interactive 3D plot with the mouse, you will see that elev and azim values are displayed in the toolbar of the window.

Comment: But my plot is not interactive. Am I missing something ? I am using spyder 5.2.2

Comment: I don't know about Spyder, probably rather a backend problem. However, if you set the elev/azim parameters, you should be able to view the 3D plot from another angle.